# catkin_make fails to build executables ROS indigo

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I face a problem using `catkin_make`. It seems that the c compiler cannot be found. the final error I am getting is  is Invoking "cmake" failed.

The environment variables seem ok:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

and the installed version of the compiler is:
cmake version 2.8.12.2

I have edited the `.bashrc` file as follows:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Please any help would be more than welcome!

The result I get from catkin_make is :

```
Base path: /home/thanos/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/install

####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/thanos/catkin_ws/src
-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 34 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - joystick_drivers (metapackage)
-- ~~  - navigation (metapackage)
-- ~~  - p2os_doc
-- ~~  - p2os_launch
-- ~~  - static_localizer
-- ~~  - move_base_msgs
-- ~~  - p2os_msgs
-- ~~  - ps3joy
-- ~~  - spacenav_node
-- ~~  - joy
-- ~~  - teleop_twist_joy
-- ~~  - fake_localization
-- ~~  - following
-- ~~  - map_server
-- ~~  - amcl
-- ~~  - p2os_driver
-- ~~  - p2os_teleop
-- ~~  - robot_pose_ekf
-- ~~  - rosaria
-- ~~  - p2os_urdf
-- ~~  - urg_node
-- ~~  - voxel_grid
-- ~~  - costmap_2d
-- ~~  - nav_core
-- ~~  - base_local_planner
-- ~~  - carrot_planner
-- ~~  - clear_costmap_recovery
-- ~~  - dwa_local_planner
-- ~~  - move_slow_and_clear
-- ~~  - navfn
-- ~~  - global_planner
-- ~~  - rotate_recovery
-- ~~  - move_base
-- ~~  - wiimote
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'joystick_drivers'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(joystick_drivers/joystick_drivers)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'navigation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/navigation)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'p2os_doc'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(p2os/p2os_doc)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'p2os_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(p2os/p2os_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'static_localizer'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(static_localizer)

... Finds all the packages and creates all the subdirectories..

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'wiimote'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(joystick_drivers/wiimote)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- wiimote: 3 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". 
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

In the CMakeErrors.log I get the following errors:

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec997468529/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec997468529.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec997468529.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec997468529.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec997468529.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec997468529
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec997468529.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec997468529.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec997468529 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec997468529.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec997468529] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec997468529/fast] Error 2

Determining if the include file FL/Fl.H exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec2890154973/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2890154973.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2890154973.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2890154973.dir/CheckIncludeFile.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -Wno-deprecated    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2890154973.dir/CheckIncludeFile.cxx.o -c /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.cxx
/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.cxx:1:19: fatal error: FL/Fl.H: No such file or directory
 #include <FL/Fl.H>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2890154973.dir/CheckIncludeFile.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2890154973/fast] Error 2
```

Please any help would be more than welcome!

---

Edit:

The conclusion was derived from the fact that there are no lines about the C/C++ compiler anywhere in the `catkin_make`, as you mentioned.
You are right about the CMake. The `catkin_make` command was working properly about a month ago. I have these problems without and significant changes in the system except for the regular updates.

I installed ROS using this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

After facing this problem I re-initialized the workspace using the following tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

**os version:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**kernel version**
3.13.0-63-generic

The output of `which gcc` is: `/usr/bin/gcc`

**Edit:**

The output of `catkin_make` in `/tmp/catkin_test/` is the following:

```
Base path: /tmp/catkin_test
Source space: /tmp/catkin_test/src
Build space: /tmp/catkin_test/build
Devel space: /tmp/catkin_test/devel
Install space: /tmp/catkin_test/install
Creating symlink "/tmp/catkin_test/src/CMakeLists.txt" pointing to "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake"
####
#### Running command: "cmake /tmp/catkin_test/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/tmp/catkin_test/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/catkin_test/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/tmp/catkin_test/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /tmp/catkin_test/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6")
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /tmp/catkin_test/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/catkin_test/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/tmp/catkin_test/build"
####
```

The output of `cmake --system-information`:

```
Avoid ctest truncation of output:
CTEST_FULL_OUTPUT

MAIN VARIABLES

CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX == "lib"
CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX == ".a"
CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX == "lib"
CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX == ".so"
CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX == "lib"
CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_SUFFIX == ".so"


CMAKE_DL_LIBS == "dl"
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH_FLAG == "-L"
CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_FLAG == "-l"
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH == "NO"
CMAKE_SYSTEM_INFO_FILE == "Platform/Linux"
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME == "Linux"
CMAKE_SYSTEM == "Linux-3.13.0-63-generic"
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER == "/usr/bin/c++"
CMAKE_C_COMPILER == "/usr/bin/cc"
CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC == "1"
CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX == "1"
```

**Edit:**
As I mentioned previously in my question I followed this tutorial [http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace] (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) in order to initialize my workspace. So after having this problem I saved the src folder of catkin_ws in another path and I erased everything under catkin_ws folder. The next step was to follow the instructions of the tutorial:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
cd ~/catkin_ws/
catkin_make

source devel/setup.bash
```

Finally, I edited the `.bashrc` as mentioned previously, copied back the src folder, but nothing changed.

**Output** of `env | grep -i ros` :

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/indigo/lib
CPATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/include:/opt/ros/indigo/include
PATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
PYTHONPATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

**Edit 4:**

I removed both lines from the `.bashrc` and I opened a new 'clean' terminal I followed again the instructions from the tutorial mentioned above in order to initialize the workspace. With an empty src folder (without the packages) I ran the `catkin_make` command and the output is the following:

```
Source space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/src Build space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build Devel space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel Install space: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/thanos/catkin_ws/src
-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/thanos/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/thanos/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/thanos/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

The next step is to run the `source devel/setup.bash` command of the tutorial and the last command

```
 echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/thanos/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

So I am at this point right now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217122/catkin_make-fails-to-build-executables-ros-indigo/) by [thandom](https://answers.ros.org/users/23773/thandom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-09-05**:
Slightly reformatted your question, to make it readable.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-06**:\

> How to use the edit link/button?

To update your question with more information, don't post *anwers*, but edit your question. There is an *edit* link (or button) right beneath where your question is displayed. Please use that for future updates.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-07**:
Just a note: console output is easier to read if you format it as *preformatted text*. Use the button with `101010` on it: select the text, then click the button (or `ctrl+k`).

**Comment by [thandom](https://answers.ros.org/users/23773/thandom/) on 2015-09-07**:
The problem seems to be on separate packages. I followed the procedure mentioned in the answer and some packages are compiled properly and some others don't. Thank you for your precious help! I will try to fix the problem in the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It seems that the c compiler cannot be found.

What lead you to that conclusion?

> and the installed version of the compiler is: cmake version 2.8.12.2

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) is not a compiler, it is a build tool.

There are some errors in the pieces of the logs you posted, but what is stranger is that there are no lines about the C/C++ compiler anywhere in the `catkin_make` output you posted.

Can you provide some more info on how you installed ROS (from source / debians), what OS this is (and which version), and what you workspace setup is? Please use the *edit* link/button for that.

A normal installation of ROS should've installed the C/C++ compilers (if they weren't already on your system). Can you also add the output of `which gcc`?

---

Edit:

> What do you mean (from source / debians)?

You can install ROS either by compiling everything yourself, or by installing pre-built binary pkgs. On Debian & Ubuntu, those packages are called *debians*. But you already linked to the tutorial you followed, so you must have installed using `apt-get`, and thus, using debians.

As to your problem: what is the output of a `catkin_make` invocation if you do the following (in a new terminal, with just `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/catkin_test/src
cd /tmp/catkin_test
catkin_make
```

Please update your question with the output you get.

Also: run `cmake --system-information` and update your question with the first few (say 25) lines (everything down to and including `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX`).

---

Edit 2:

Based on this:

> ```
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
> ```

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
[..]
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
[..]
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
```

and this:

> ```
> CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER == "/usr/bin/c++"
> ```

```
CMAKE_C_COMPILER == "/usr/bin/cc"
```

I'd say there is nothing really wrong with your system. It's more likely a workspace related issue (so setup and / or packages in it).

Can you tell us *exactly* (ie: copy/paste the commands you used in your question) how you created and set up your workspace? Please edit your question with that information.

Also: in a normal terminal (so one which may source your problematic workspace) run `env | grep -i ros` and append the output of that to your question.

---

Edit 3:

> ```
> source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
> ```

was this in a 'clean' terminal? So without the `source /opt/..` lines in your `.bashrc`?

> ```
> mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
> ```

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
```

You don't need this last command

> ```
> cd ~/catkin_ws/
> ```

```
catkin_make
```

So at this point there were no packages in `~/catkin_ws/src`?

> ```
> source devel/setup.bash
> ```

Again, was this in a clean terminal / bash session? If not, please remove the lines from your `.bashrc` and try again.

Also:

> I have edited the `.bashrc` file as follows:

> ```
> source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
> ```

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

You don't need to source the distribution `setup.bash` and the workspace file. Just source the workspace file, it sets up everything else for you.

Finally: it could be that one or more of your pkgs are doing something strange that is messing up CMake / catkin. Please try starting with a clean terminal, an empty - new - workspace, and add pkgs one by one to see when things stop working.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2